# Python extract session id from string url

Tags: python, regex

I have a url:

> mywebsite.com/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO;jsessionid=CED11D31669BEAB45B4CDA651C7EBF3B.idp03?execution=e1s1

I want to extract the jsessionid value after the semicolon but before the .idp03: CED11D31669BEAB45B4CDA651C7EBF3B

How might I do this with Python?

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

s = '/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO;jsessionid=CED11D31669BEAB45B4CDA651C7EBF3B.idp03?execution=e1s1'

re.findall('jsessionid=(.*)\.',s)
# ['CED11D31669BEAB45B4CDA651C7EBF3B']
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a fast response! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a more cautious pattern here, that would check for one of the termination conditions of the `jsessionid`:

- . in case there is an extension
- ? in case there is no extension `.idp03`
- $ in case there is no extension AND no query parameter

Putting this into together we have this:

```
input = '/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO;jsessionid=CED11D31669BEAB45B4CDA651C7EBF3B.idp03?execution=e1s1'
result = re.search(r'jsessionid=(.*?)(?=[.?]|$)', input)

if result:
    print "jsessionid : ", result.group(1)
else:
    print "no jsessionid found"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. (?<=jsessionid=) match left begain with `jsessionid=`
2. \w+ match any word character (letter, number)

the code:

```
import re
s = "mywebsite.com/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO;jsessionid=CED11D31669BEAB45B4CDA651C7EBF3B.idp03?execution=e1s1"
print(re.findall(r"(?<=jsessionid=)\w+",s)) # ['CED11D31669BEAB45B4CDA651C7EBF3B']
```